# SQL - type is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, double

I have to use...

Code of C#

```
public double price { get; set; }
```

Code of SQL

```
Select id, (0.0) AS price from Product
```

but during this code I got this error:

> "ExceptionMessage":"The specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Decimal' type to a nullable 'System.Double' type is not valid."

Also I don't want to change code of c#, For solving I want to change code of Sql (not c#)

Comment: cast your sql value to double in C# side `price = (double) dbValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (0.0) return a numeric type, which is [mapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) to Decimal. All you need is to cast into float, which is mapped to double, so :

```
SELECT id, cast(0.0 as float) AS price from Product
```

should do the trick.